# Fast Exp calculation: possible to improve accuracy without losing too much performance?

Tags: c#, performance, floating-accuracy, exp

I am trying out the fast Exp(x) function that previously was described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412988/650012) answer to an SO question on improving calculation speed in C#:

```
public static double Exp(double x)
{
  var tmp = (long)(1512775 * x + 1072632447);
  return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(tmp << 32);
}
```

The expression is using some IEEE floating point "tricks" and is primarily intended for use in neural sets. The function is approximately 5 times faster than the regular `Math.Exp(x)` function.

Unfortunately, the numeric accuracy is only -4% -- +2% relative to the regular `Math.Exp(x)` function, ideally I would like to have accuracy within at least the sub-percent range.

I have plotted the quotient between the approximate and the regular Exp functions, and as can be seen in the graph the relative difference appears to be repeated with practically constant frequency.

[image: Quotient between fast and regular exp function]

Is it possible to take advantage of this regularity to improve the accuracy of the "fast exp" function further without substantially reducing the calculation speed, or would the computational overhead of an accuracy improvement outweigh the computational gain of the original expression?

(As a side note, I have also tried [one of the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412102/650012) approaches proposed in the same SO question, but this approach does not seem to be computationally efficient in C#, at least not for the general case.)

**UPDATE MAY 14**

Upon request from @Adriano, I have now performed a very simple benchmark. I have performed 10 million computations using each of the alternative *exp* functions for floating point values in the range [-100, 100]. Since the range of values I am interested in spans from -20 to 0 I have also explicitly listed the function value at x = -5. Here are the results:

```
      Math.Exp: 62.525 ms, exp(-5) = 0.00673794699908547
Empty function: 13.769 ms
     ExpNeural: 14.867 ms, exp(-5) = 0.00675211846828461
    ExpSeries8: 15.121 ms, exp(-5) = 0.00641270968867667
   ExpSeries16: 32.046 ms, exp(-5) = 0.00673666189488182
          exp1: 15.062 ms, exp(-5) = -12.3333325982094
          exp2: 15.090 ms, exp(-5) = 13.708332516253
          exp3: 16.251 ms, exp(-5) = -12.3333325982094
          exp4: 17.924 ms, exp(-5) = 728.368055056781
          exp5: 20.972 ms, exp(-5) = -6.13293614238501
          exp6: 24.212 ms, exp(-5) = 3.55518353166184
          exp7: 29.092 ms, exp(-5) = -1.8271053775984
      exp7 +/-: 38.482 ms, exp(-5) = 0.00695945286970704
```

*ExpNeural* is equivalent to the *Exp* function specified in the beginning of this text. *ExpSeries8* is the [formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412102/650012) that I originally claimed was not very efficient on .NET; when implementing it exactly like Neil it was actually very fast. *ExpSeries16* is the analogous formula but with 16 multiplications instead of 8. *exp1* through *exp7* are the different functions from Adriano's answer below. The final variant of *exp7* is a variant where the sign of *x* is checked; if negative the function returns `1/exp(-x)` instead.

Unfortunately, neither of the *expN* functions listed by [Adriano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552567/650012) are sufficient in the broader negative value range I am considering. The series expansion approach by [Neil Coffey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412102/650012) seems to be more suitable in "my" value range, although it is too rapidly diverging with larger negative *x*, especially when using "only" 8 multiplications.

Comment: i'm curious about your reference to "neural sets."  currently i'm simulating a neural network using C++ and facing the same `exp` performance bottleneck you've faced.  are there papers within computational neuroscience that have proposed approximate `exp` functions that are very fast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case anyone wants to replicate the relative error function shown in the question, here's a way using Matlab (the "fast" exponent is not very fast in Matlab, but it is accurate):

```
t = 1072632447+[0:ceil(1512775*pi)];
x = (t - 1072632447)/1512775;
ex = exp(x);
t = uint64(t);
import java.lang.Double;
et = arrayfun( @(n) java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(bitshift(n,32)), t );
plot(x, et./ex);
```

Now, the period of the error exactly coincides with when the binary value of `tmp` overflows from the mantissa into the exponent.  Let's break our data into bins by discarding the bits that become the exponent (making it periodic), and keeping only the high eight remaining bits (to make our lookup table a reasonable size):

```
index = bitshift(bitand(t,uint64(2^20-2^12)),-12) + 1;
```

Now we calculate the mean required adjustment:

```
relerrfix = ex./et;
adjust = NaN(1,256);
for i=1:256; adjust(i) = mean(relerrfix(index == i)); end;
et2 = et .* adjust(index);
```

The relative error is decreased to +/- .0006.  Of course, other tables sizes are possible as well (for example, a 6-bit table with 64 entries gives +/- .0025) and the error is almost linear in table size.  Linear interpolation between table entries would improve the error yet further, but at the expense of performance.  Since we've already met the accuracy goal, let's avoid any further performance hits.

At this point it's some trivial editor skills to take the values computed by MatLab and create a lookup table in C#.  For each computation, we add a bitmask, table lookup, and double-precision multiply.

```
static double FastExp(double x)
{
    var tmp = (long)(1512775 * x + 1072632447);
    int index = (int)(tmp >> 12) & 0xFF;
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(tmp << 32) * ExpAdjustment[index];
}
```

The speedup is very similar to the original code -- for my computer, this is about 30% faster compiled as x86 and about 3x as fast for x64.  With mono on ideone, it's a substantial net loss (but so is [the original](http://ideone.com/HDcMF)).

Complete source code and testcase: http://ideone.com/UwNgx

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace fastexponent
{
    class Program
    {
        static double[] ExpAdjustment = new double[256] {
            1.040389835,
            1.039159306,
            1.037945888,
            1.036749401,
            1.035569671,
            1.034406528,
            1.033259801,
            1.032129324,
            1.031014933,
            1.029916467,
            1.028833767,
            1.027766676,
            1.02671504,
            1.025678708,
            1.02465753,
            1.023651359,
            1.022660049,
            1.021683458,
            1.020721446,
            1.019773873,
            1.018840604,
            1.017921503,
            1.017016438,
            1.016125279,
            1.015247897,
            1.014384165,
            1.013533958,
            1.012697153,
            1.011873629,
            1.011063266,
            1.010265947,
            1.009481555,
            1.008709975,
            1.007951096,
            1.007204805,
            1.006470993,
            1.005749552,
            1.005040376,
            1.004343358,
            1.003658397,
            1.002985389,
            1.002324233,
            1.001674831,
            1.001037085,
            1.000410897,
            0.999796173,
            0.999192819,
            0.998600742,
            0.998019851,
            0.997450055,
            0.996891266,
            0.996343396,
            0.995806358,
            0.995280068,
            0.99476444,
            0.994259393,
            0.993764844,
            0.993280711,
            0.992806917,
            0.992343381,
            0.991890026,
            0.991446776,
            0.991013555,
            0.990590289,
            0.990176903,
            0.989773325,
            0.989379484,
            0.988995309,
            0.988620729,
            0.988255677,
            0.987900083,
            0.987553882,
            0.987217006,
            0.98688939,
            0.98657097,
            0.986261682,
            0.985961463,
            0.985670251,
            0.985387985,
            0.985114604,
            0.984850048,
            0.984594259,
            0.984347178,
            0.984108748,
            0.983878911,
            0.983657613,
            0.983444797,
            0.983240409,
            0.983044394,
            0.982856701,
            0.982677276,
            0.982506066,
            0.982343022,
            0.982188091,
            0.982041225,
            0.981902373,
            0.981771487,
            0.981648519,
            0.981533421,
            0.981426146,
            0.981326648,
            0.98123488,
            0.981150798,
            0.981074356,
            0.981005511,
            0.980944219,
            0.980890437,
            0.980844122,
            0.980805232,
            0.980773726,
            0.980749562,
            0.9807327,
            0.9807231,
            0.980720722,
            0.980725528,
            0.980737478,
            0.980756534,
            0.98078266,
            0.980815817,
            0.980855968,
            0.980903079,
            0.980955475,
            0.981017942,
            0.981085714,
            0.981160303,
            0.981241675,
            0.981329796,
            0.981424634,
            0.981526154,
            0.981634325,
            0.981749114,
            0.981870489,
            0.981998419,
            0.982132873,
            0.98227382,
            0.982421229,
            0.982575072,
            0.982735318,
            0.982901937,
            0.983074902,
            0.983254183,
            0.983439752,
            0.983631582,
            0.983829644,
            0.984033912,
            0.984244358,
            0.984460956,
            0.984683681,
            0.984912505,
            0.985147403,
            0.985388349,
            0.98563532,
            0.98588829,
            0.986147234,
            0.986412128,
            0.986682949,
            0.986959673,
            0.987242277,
            0.987530737,
            0.987825031,
            0.988125136,
            0.98843103,
            0.988742691,
            0.989060098,
            0.989383229,
            0.989712063,
            0.990046579,
            0.990386756,
            0.990732574,
            0.991084012,
            0.991441052,
            0.991803672,
            0.992171854,
            0.992545578,
            0.992924825,
            0.993309578,
            0.993699816,
            0.994095522,
            0.994496677,
            0.994903265,
            0.995315266,
            0.995732665,
            0.996155442,
            0.996583582,
            0.997017068,
            0.997455883,
            0.99790001,
            0.998349434,
            0.998804138,
            0.999264107,
            0.999729325,
            1.000199776,
            1.000675446,
            1.001156319,
            1.001642381,
            1.002133617,
            1.002630011,
            1.003131551,
            1.003638222,
            1.00415001,
            1.004666901,
            1.005188881,
            1.005715938,
            1.006248058,
            1.006785227,
            1.007327434,
            1.007874665,
            1.008426907,
            1.008984149,
            1.009546377,
            1.010113581,
            1.010685747,
            1.011262865,
            1.011844922,
            1.012431907,
            1.013023808,
            1.013620615,
            1.014222317,
            1.014828902,
            1.01544036,
            1.016056681,
            1.016677853,
            1.017303866,
            1.017934711,
            1.018570378,
            1.019210855,
            1.019856135,
            1.020506206,
            1.02116106,
            1.021820687,
            1.022485078,
            1.023154224,
            1.023828116,
            1.024506745,
            1.025190103,
            1.02587818,
            1.026570969,
            1.027268461,
            1.027970647,
            1.02867752,
            1.029389072,
            1.030114973,
            1.030826088,
            1.03155163,
            1.032281819,
            1.03301665,
            1.033756114,
            1.034500204,
            1.035248913,
            1.036002235,
            1.036760162,
            1.037522688,
            1.038289806,
            1.039061509,
            1.039837792,
            1.040618648
        };

        static double FastExp(double x)
        {
            var tmp = (long)(1512775 * x + 1072632447);
            int index = (int)(tmp >> 12) & 0xFF;
            return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(tmp << 32) * ExpAdjustment[index];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] x = new double[1000000];
            double[] ex = new double[x.Length];
            double[] fx = new double[x.Length];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
                x[i] = r.NextDouble() * 40;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; ++j)
                ex[j] = Math.Exp(x[j]);
            sw.Stop();
            double builtin = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int k = 0; k < x.Length; ++k)
                fx[k] = FastExp(x[k]);
            sw.Stop();
            double custom = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

            double min = 1, max = 1;
            for (int m = 0; m < x.Length; ++m) {
                double ratio = fx[m] / ex[m];
                if (min > ratio) min = ratio;
                if (max < ratio) max = ratio;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("minimum ratio = " + min.ToString() + ", maximum ratio = " + max.ToString() + ", speedup = " + (builtin / custom).ToString());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic work, and a great explanation! Many thanks for providing this answer, this was just the kind of progress I had hoped for. Had you developed this earlier, or did you implement it as a result of this question?

Comment: @Anders: I totally stole the approach you suggested in the question.

Comment: After testing in android NDK, it's slower than system std::exp(). But it's faster in PC. (https://gist.github.com/maxint/0172c1dcd075d3589eeb)

Comment: @maxint: That code has undefined behavior written all over it.  Use `memcpy` for your type-punning.  Anyway, depending on whether your target has floating-point hardware, you might want to use single-precision for the lookup table.  We are talking about a relative error of .0006, so double precision isn't helping.

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you have a C implementation of this?

Comment: @a3mlord: Simply replace `BitConverter` functions by a `memcpy`, and move the `[]` in the array definition.  The rest of the C# code is valid C already.

Answer (score 15):

Taylor series approximations (such as the `expX()` functions in [Adriano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552567/1339280)) are most accurate near zero and can have huge errors at -20 or even -5. If the input has a known range, such as -20 to 0 like the original question, you can use a small look up table and one additional multiply to greatly improve accuracy.

The trick is to recognize that exp() can be separated into integer and fractional parts. For example:

```
exp(-2.345) = exp(-2.0) * exp(-0.345)
```

The fractional part will always be between -1 and 1, so a Taylor series approximation will be pretty accurate. The integer part has only 21 possible values for exp(-20) to exp(0), so these can be stored in a small look up table.

Answer (score 14):

Try following alternatives (`exp1` is faster, `exp7` is more precise).

**Code**

```
public static double exp1(double x) { 
    return (6+x*(6+x*(3+x)))*0.16666666f; 
}

public static double exp2(double x) {
    return (24+x*(24+x*(12+x*(4+x))))*0.041666666f;
}

public static double exp3(double x) {
    return (120+x*(120+x*(60+x*(20+x*(5+x)))))*0.0083333333f;
}

public static double exp4(double x) {
    return 720+x*(720+x*(360+x*(120+x*(30+x*(6+x))))))*0.0013888888f;
}

public static double exp5(double x) {
    return (5040+x*(5040+x*(2520+x*(840+x*(210+x*(42+x*(7+x)))))))*0.00019841269f;
}

public static double exp6(double x) {
    return (40320+x*(40320+x*(20160+x*(6720+x*(1680+x*(336+x*(56+x*(8+x))))))))*2.4801587301e-5;
}

public static double exp7(double x) {
  return (362880+x*(362880+x*(181440+x*(60480+x*(15120+x*(3024+x*(504+x*(72+x*(9+x)))))))))*2.75573192e-6;
}
```

**Precision**

```
Function     Error in [-1...1]              Error in [3.14...3.14]

exp1         0.05           1.8%            8.8742         38.40%
exp2         0.01           0.36%           4.8237         20.80%
exp3         0.0016152      0.59%           2.28            9.80%
exp4         0.0002263      0.0083%         0.9488          4.10%
exp5         0.0000279      0.001%          0.3516          1.50%
exp6         0.0000031      0.00011%        0.1172          0.50%
exp7         0.0000003      0.000011%       0.0355          0.15%
```

**Credits**
These implementations of `exp()` have been calculated by "scoofy" using Taylor series from a `tanh()` implementation of "fuzzpilz" (whoever they are, I just had these references on my code).

Comment: "fuzzpilz" LOL. Some people have a weird sense for nick names.

Comment: Original Taylor series approximation by scoofy@inf.elte.hu here: http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=222 - Upvoted as it's a straightforward solution via the Taylor series, surprised it hasn't been posted before.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi thank you for the reference, it's gone lost long time ago!

Comment: Many Thanks, Adriano, for providing these methods, and thanks Mahmoud for providing the link to the original text. I had not come across these implementations before. I have tried exp7, and it is approximately three times faster than Math.Exp. For negative x it diverges quite rapidly, but that could maybe be accounted for by calculating 1/exp(abs(x))? I will review my own code to see if the interval of x values is sufficient for using exp7, and if it is I am more than willing to accept your answer, Adriano.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson please update your question (or post an answer) with your test results, I'm using this function (actually exp5) in a C++ program so I never tried its performance in .NET. I don't know how performance of 1/exp(abs(x)) will be, maybe not so far from Math.Exp. If you have to use it in a (per layer) loop you may consider to implement this function in a C++/CLI library, there you'll be able to use inline assembly with SIMD instructions over the loop (if this doesn't force you to refactor your code too much).

Comment: @Adriano, sorry for not responding any sooner. I will update the question with my test results as soon as possible, and I will test C/C++ exp for comparison at the same time. I have been using the Parallel functionality in .NET 4, although in this particular case I have not yet prepared the code for parallelization. Will look into this as well.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thank you, I'm pretty interested. I didn't mean the .NET Parallel Library (I guess to make it parallel will cause some refactoring) but something like this (in case it's possible): http://stackoverflow.com/a/412831/1207195

Comment: @Adriano, I have updated my question with some benchmark timings now. I also did a closer check of the value range that is relevant to my application, and the values typically range from 0 to negative hundreds. Values of -10 -- -15 will have a significant impact on the end result, so accuracy at least down to these values is relevant. BTW, thanks for the suggestion on calculating in C++, I see now what you mean. It will require substantial refactoring in my case, but maybe it's worth it; I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson yes, it works well only in the +/- 3.14 range but thanks for the benchmark!!!

Comment: @AndersGustafsson [The technique described in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14143184/1339280) will greatly improve accuracy over a wide range of inputs.

Answer (score 8):

The following code should address the accuracy requirements, as for inputs in [-87,88] the results have relative error <= 1.73e-3. I do not know C#, so this is C code, but I assume conversion should be fairly straightforward.

I assume that since the accuracy requirement is low, the use of single-precision computation is fine. A classic algorithm is being used in which the computation of exp() is mapped to computation of exp2(). After argument conversion via multiplication by log2(e), exponentation by the fractional part is handled using a minimax polynomial of degree 2, while exponentation by the integral part of the argument is performed by direct manipulation of the exponent part of the IEEE-754 single-precision number.

The volatile union facilitates re-interpretation of a bit pattern as either an integer or a single-precision floating-point number, needed for the exponent manipulation. It looks like C# offers decidated re-interpretation functions for this, which is much cleaner.

The two potential performance problems are the floor() function and float->int conversion. Traditionally both were slow on x86 due to the need to handle dynamic processor state. But SSE (in particular SSE 4.1) provides instructions that allow these operations to be fast. I do not know whether C# can make use of those instructions.

```
 /* max. rel. error <= 1.73e-3 on [-87,88] */
 float fast_exp (float x)
 {
   volatile union {
     float f;
     unsigned int i;
   } cvt;

   /* exp(x) = 2^i * 2^f; i = floor (log2(e) * x), 0 <= f <= 1 */
   float t = x * 1.442695041f;
   float fi = floorf (t);
   float f = t - fi;
   int i = (int)fi;
   cvt.f = (0.3371894346f * f + 0.657636276f) * f + 1.00172476f; /* compute 2^f */
   cvt.i += (i << 23);                                          /* scale by 2^i */
   return cvt.f;
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks for a great example and a good explanation. I will try to convert your implementation in C# to see how well it performs compared with the regular _Exp_ function. I can't remember having seen this solution anywhere else, did you come up with this as a result of the SO question?

Comment: I have designed / implemented algorithms for various transcendental functions multiple times in the past. The approach I chose above is very much a garden-variety algorithm. I did create a custom minimax approximation for the polynomial specifically in response to this question. There are tools for this such as Mathematica, Maple, and others; generally they are based on variants of the Remez algorithm.

Comment: Do note that it isn't correct in C++ to use the union.  But you can use `memcpy` in both C and C++, and the optimizer should do something sensible, without breaking it with optimizations based on strict aliasing.

Comment: @njuffa, Do you have SSE version of it (Operating on `__m128`)? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi I don't have any SSE code ready to post, and haven't programmed with SSE intrinsics since I switched to GPUs ten years ago.

Comment: @Royi I have an SSE version of this code now. I would suggest asking a question for a low precision `expf()` SIMD-implementation and I could then supply an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have studied the [paper](http://nic.schraudolph.org/pubs/Schraudolph99.pdf) by Nicol Schraudolph where the original C implementation of the above function was defined in more detail now. It does seem that it is probably not possible to substantially approve the accuracy of the *exp* computation without severely impacting the performance. On the other hand, the approximation is valid also for large magnitudes of *x*, up to +/- 700, which is of course advantageous.

The function implementation above is tuned to obtain minimum root mean square error. Schraudolph describes how the additive term in the *tmp* expression can be altered to achieve alternative approximation properties.

```
"exp" >= exp for all x                      1072693248 -  (-1) = 1072693249
"exp" <= exp for all x                                 - 90253 = 1072602995
"exp" symmetric around exp                             - 45799 = 1072647449
Mimimum possible mean deviation                        - 68243 = 1072625005
Minimum possible root-mean-square deviation            - 60801 = 1072632447
```

He also points out that at a "microscopic" level the approximate "exp" function exhibits stair-case behavior since 32 bits are discarded in the conversion from *long* to *double*. This means that the function is piece-wise constant on a very small scale, but the function is at least never decreasing with increasing *x*.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed for my purposes the following function that calculates quickly and accurately the natural exponent with single precision. The algorithm is based on the Chebyshev method. The function works in the entire range of float values. The code is written under Visual Studio (x86).

```
_declspec(naked) float _vectorcall fexp(float x)
{
  static const float ct[7] =       // Constants table
  {
    1.44269502f,                   // lb(e)
    1.92596299E-8f,                // Correction to the value lb(e)
    -9.21120925E-4f,               // 16*b2
    0.115524396f,                  // 4*b1
    2.88539004f,                   // b0
    2.0f,                          // 2
    4.65661287E-10f                // 2^-31
  };
  _asm
  {
    mov ecx,offset ct              // ecx contains the address of constants tables
    vmulss xmm1,xmm0,[ecx]         // xmm1 = x*lb(e)
    vcvtss2si eax,xmm1             // eax = round(x*lb(e)) = k
    vmovss xmm3,[ecx+8]            // Initialize the sum with highest coefficient 16*b2
    cdq                            // edx=-1, if x<0 or overflow, otherwise edx=0
    vcvtsi2ss xmm1,xmm1,eax        // xmm1 = k
    and edx,4                      // edx=4, if x<0, otherwise edx=0
    vfmsub231ss xmm1,xmm0,[ecx]    // xmm1 = x*lb(e)-k = t/2 in the range from -0.5 to 0.5
    lea eax,[eax+8*edx]            // Add 32 to exponent, if x<0
    vfmadd231ss xmm1,xmm0,[ecx+4]  // xmm1 = t/2 (corrected value)
    add eax,126                    // The exponent of 2^(k-1) or 2^(k+31) with shift +127
    jle exp_break                  // Break, if x<<0, x>>0 or x=NaN
    vmulss xmm2,xmm1,xmm1          // xmm2 = t^2/4 - the argument of polynomial
    cmp eax,254                    // Check that the exponent is not too large
    jg exp_inf                     // Jump to set Inf if overflow
    vfmadd213ss xmm3,xmm2,[ecx+12] // xmm3 = 4*b1+4*b2*t^2
    shl eax,23                     // eax contains the bits of 2^(k-1) or 2^(k+31)
    vfmsub213ss xmm3,xmm2,xmm1     // xmm3 = -t/2+b1*t^2+b2*t^4
    vaddss xmm0,xmm1,xmm1          // xmm0 = t
    vaddss xmm3,xmm3,[ecx+16]      // xmm3 = b0-t/2+b1*t^2+b2*t^4 = f(t)-t/2
    vmovd xmm1,eax                 // xmm1 = 2^(k+31), if x<0; otherwise 2^(k-1)
    vdivss xmm0,xmm0,xmm3          // xmm0 = t/(f(t)-t/2)
    vfmadd213ss xmm0,xmm1,xmm1     // xmm0 = e^x with the shift of exponent by -1 or 31
    vmulss xmm0,xmm0,[ecx+edx+20]  // xmm0 = e^x
    ret                            // Return
      exp_break:                   // Form the result 0, Inf or NaN
    vucomiss xmm0,[ecx]            // Test the sign of x and the condition x=NaN
    jp exp_end                     // Exit with result NaN, if x=NaN
      exp_inf:                     // Entry point for forming result Inf
    vxorps xmm0,xmm0,xmm0          // xmm0 = 0
    jc exp_end                     // Ready, if x<<0
    vrcpss xmm0,xmm0,xmm0          // xmm0 = Inf at case x>>0
      exp_end:                     // Result at xmm0 is done
    ret                            // Return
  }
}
```

Comment: How well does this implementation compare with the others presented in the answers above, in terms of speed and accuracy?

Comment: I performed a comparative test with the function FastExp marked with a tick. I rewrote it for C++ under Visual Studio 2019.

Results:
ExpFast function: RMS relative error = 0.000158053; time = 1297 ms.
My fexp function: RMS relative error = 1.56881e-07; time = 578 ms.
Standard expf function: RMS relative error = 1.564e-07; time = 1437 ms.

Comment: Thanks. Please note though that the question refers to C#.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't write in c#, but my code can be useful in any environment that supports assembler inserts.

Answer (score 1):

For a sort of meta-review of the various answers proposed above, I coded the routines in C# and tested the error over the range of -87 to +88, incrementing by 0.1 (except between -10 and +10 where I incremented by 0.01 for finer resolution):

- **A function using @Adriano 's `exp3()`** for the fractional part combined with a lookup table for the integer part of a float on range [-88, 88]:

  - max |error|: **0.308%**
  - avg |error|: **0.009%**
  - average speedup relative to `Math.Exp()`: **30.86%**
  - This had the lowest avg |error| (*not max |error|*), but the speedup was not that impressive.
- **@njuffa answer for float**:

  - max |error|: **0.173%**
  - avg |error|: **0.108%**
  - average speedup relative to `Math.Exp()`: **43.52%**
  - I implemented this using the C# struct with StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit). This answer had the potential to be 60% faster than `Math.Exp()`. Unfortunately to mimic the `Math.Floor()` (which is too slow), you need to use `(int)flt` truncation; but for negative values, it's this truncation -1 (since the cast to int is towards zero). I could not find a *fast* way to mimic this behavior. Even a single `if` comparison (`flt < 0f`), caused the performance to drop from around 60% down to 43.5% (and I tried a lot of different variations--too bad).
- **@BenVoigt answer for double**:

  - max |error|: **0.060%**
  - avg |error|: **0.012%**
  - average speedup relative to `Math.Exp()` (after bounds correction): **45.97%**
  - Ben's adjustment lookup table greatly reduced the average and max errors, at the cost of about -10% of the speedup in the poster's original function.
  - This solution also suffers from catastrophic exponent overflow at the extreme ends of the range of `x`. So you have to check the bounds first (see the corrected function at the bottom of this post).
- **@AndersGustafsson original posted function for double**:

  - max |error|: **3.940%**
  - avg |error|: **1.520%**
  - average speedup relative to `Math.Exp()` (after bounds correction): **55.55%**
  - The original 2-line function posted at the top was the fastest I found, albeit with the largest error.
  - This solution also suffers from catastrophic exponent overflow at the extreme ends of the range of `x`. So you have to check the bounds first (similar to the corrected function at the bottom of this post).

My conclusion is that **@BenVoigt's answer** (after the bounds checks correction) is the winner, unless you can tolerate the error in the original posted function. If coding in C/C++ you have many additional faster options using SSE intrinsics, assembly, etc. (see the SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025373/fastest-implementation-of-the-natural-exponential-function-using-sse) for more details).

```
static double FastExp(double x)
{
    // must check bounds first!
    if (x < -709)
        return 0.0;
    else if (x > 709)
        return double.PositiveInfinity;

    var tmp = (long)(1512775 * x + 1072632447);
    int index = (int)(tmp >> 12) & 0xFF;
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(tmp << 32) * ExpAdjustment[index];
}
```